# Function fires when a FlatList item comes to View

Tags: react-native, react-native-ios, react-native-flatlist

I have a basic flat list as follows.

```
  <FlatList
    numColumns={2}
    data={items}
    renderItem={() => (
      <Item />
    )
    }
  />
```

I am trying hide/display another component based on whether the first four items are in view.

In order to do so I have to first figure out if a certain element is in view or not. How can I approach this problem?

Comment: what do you want to happen when you scroll away from the first four items (they have rendered but are no longer in view)?

Comment: I actually want to trigger some changes via a function when the first four element are not visible on the screen.

Comment: Okay, I'd first put a console.log() in the `componentDidMount`, `componentDidUnmount` and `render` in `<Item/>` to find out if your item unmounts on scrolling away. I'd also set the Flatlist prop `initialNumToRender` to 0. Hopefully it does unmount.

Comment: You can pass in the item index too https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/flatlist.html#renderitem

Answer (score 0):

If you set the Flatlist prop `initialNumToRender` to 0, and check to see if your items unmount on scrolling away, you can easily write a `componentDidMount` and `componentDidUnmount` that fires if the [flatlist item index](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/flatlist.html#renderitem) is less than 4.

If that doesn't work I'd try writing a wrapper component that tracks the position of the 4th component.

Whatever your container component renders might be

```
render() {
  return (
    <>
      <Flatlist 
        initialNumToRender={4}
        renderItem={({ index }) => (
          <>
            {index === 4 ? (     
              <PositionAwareView 
                setFourItemsInView={this.setFourItemsInView}
                id={index}
              >
                <Item 
                  setFourItemsInView={this.setFourItemsInView}
                  index={index}
                />
              <PositionAwareView />
            ) : <Item />}
          </>
        )}
      />
      {fourItemsInView ? <Stuff /> : null}
    </>
  )
}
```

1. Set the Flatlist prop `initialNumToRender` to 4 so those first four items never get unmounted.
2. pass a function `setFourItemsInView` as a prop to your 4th Item that modifies a boolean `fourItemsInView` in your container component (the one with the Flatlist)
3. on componentDidMount of the 4th Item component trigger `setFourItemsInView(true)`.
4. Write a wrapper component that tracks the position called `PositionAwareView` and call `setFourItemsInView` when the 4th item is out of screen.

This is a start on that in Typescript.

```
import * as React from 'react';
import { View } from 'react-native';

interface IPositionAwareViewProps {
  id: string;
  setFourItemsInView: any;
}
// interface IPositionAwareViewState {}

class PositionAwareView extends React.Component<IPositionAwareViewProps, {}> {
  public state = {
    ref: null
  };
  public ref: View | null;

  public constructor(props: IPositionAwareViewProps) {
    super(props);
    this.ref = null;
  }

  public componentDidMount() {}

  public render() {
    return (
      <View ref={ref => (this.ref = ref)} onLayout={this.onLayout}>
        {this.props.children}
      </View>
    );
  }

  private onLayout = () => {
    if (this.ref) {
      this.ref.measure((x, y, width, height, pageX, pageY) => {
        console.log(this.props.id, 'PositionAwareView x y X Y', x, y, pageX, pageY);
      });
    }
  };
}

export default PositionAwareView;
```

You'll also need to be careful about different screen sizes, the notches (especially in android) and portrait vs landscape orientation.

Disclaimer: not sure how well this will work. Maybe it'd be better to ignore the position tracking and just use `setFourItemsInView` in `componentDidMount` of another, later item.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use `viewabilityConfig` and `onViewableItemsChanged`

`onViewableItemsChanged` will return an viewable object with information about changed FlatList item state and items viewable on screen.